# Level 2 Menger Sponge

Tags: gn.general-topology

Hi fellows,

Does anyone know the number of holes of a level 2 Menger Sponge ?

Comment: While I love having questions about fractals on the site, I don't think this one is quite at the research level that is generally expected here. Best of luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n=1$, $g=5$: you drill a vertical hole through the middle and four horizontal holes to meet that vertical hole.

For higher values of $n$, the right way to think of it is in terms of Euler characteristic.

For $n=2$ you start with $20$ copies of a small level $1$ Menger sponge, with Euler characteristic $-8$. You then glue them together a bunch of times on an annulus. The annulus has Euler characteristic $0$, so the final Euler characteristic is $-160$, giving a genus of $81$.

The side of a level $n$ Menger sponge has Euler characteristic $(8-8^n)/7$. In general you glue along $24$ of these, so the recurrence relation for the Euler characteristic is $\chi_{n+1}=20\chi_n + 24 (8^n-8)/7$.

This recurrence relation can produce an explicit formula, but it seems rather awful.

Answer (score 0):

What does "hole" mean?  All the empty spaces are connected to each other, so probably you should say there is one hole.

[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge)

Comment: by "holes", I meant topological genus.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the answer is supposed to be 2^n, where n is the level of the sponge. Not quite so sure though, as I was told so in class very long ago, and I misplaced the paper...